# Children route param unavailable

Tags: angular, angular-router

That's the second time I'm experiencing something curious in Angular router.
I'm currently using Angular v4.3.1.

I'm using the same component, for creating and editing objects.
That's the reason I want to define two routes for this component, one with an id, the other one without.

I tried to create the following route:

```
{
    path: 'company/settings/survey',
    component: SurveyComponent,
    children:[
      {path:':id',
      component:SurveyComponent
      }
    ]
}
```

but with this case, my id param is never set.

I'm retrieving it with:

```
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params) => {
    if (params.has('id')) {
        //Some stuff
    }
  }
```

I'm currently using a failback:

```
  {
    path: 'company/settings/survey',
    component: SurveyComponent,
  }, {
    path:'company/settings/survey/:id',
    component: SurveyComponent
  }
```

but I'd like to understand the reason my first solution isn't working.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
{
    path: 'company/settings/survey',
    children:[
      {
          path:'',  component:SurveyComponent
      },
      {
          path:':id',  component:SurveyComponent
      },
    ]
}
```

then

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {}
this.route.paramMap.get('id');
.......
```

Comment: Well that's good !
With this answer and the explanation provided by @justin juste above I better understand the behavior I got, and the one that I get !

Answer (score 1):

In your first example your code would be trying to route to a SurveyComponent within another SurveyComponent which I dont think is what you are intending to do.

Child routes are loaded into the `<router-outlet>` within the parent component